# ECMAScript 6 child class prints with parents name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When I do a `console.log(object)` I expect to see the name of the object's class. So it seems rather unexpected that a child class carries the name of its parent.

```
"use strict";

class Parent {
  constructor () {
  }
}
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
}
class Grandchild extends Child {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }
}

var grandchild = new Grandchild();

console.log(grandchild); // Parent {}
console.log(grandchild.constructor.name); // Grandchild
console.log(grandchild instanceof Parent); // true
console.log(grandchild instanceof Child); // true
console.log(JSON.stringify(grandchild)); // {}
```

Is this intended behaviour? Is it the `console.log` that's messing it up, or does JavaScript consider instances of any descendant class to be, first and foremost, the instance of the root level class?

Comment: The console is implementation dependent. On Firefox I get `Object {  }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`console` is not standard, as you can see [in its MDN entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console). The standard way to get the class name of an instance in ES6 is to use `instance.contructor.name`. This is stated in [the spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-runtime-semantics-bindingclassdeclarationevaluation).